# Custom ggplot output (colour, appearence, etc)

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, legend

I am quite new to ggplot2, so forgive me if this post is too stupid. 
I used the following code to plot the data, but I am not able to get the style that I need for publication.

In the output, I need:

1. a legend. In my data case, there is nothing after `opts(legend.position="top")` I have no idea why. And I also would like to split the legend into 3 columns like `columns=3` in `auto.key` of lattice
2. Colorize the bars using grey system (eg, `fill=c("white","grey20","grey70")`)according to factor `pl`, but it seems that I cannot change the style with `scale_colour_manual`
3. turn around the labels on the x-axis into horizontal.
4. maybe a y-axis? But,do you think it is necessary?

BTW, I have no idea how to prepare a figure for publication, so, any suggestion is very welcome!

```
library(ggplot2)
wt<-gl(3,4,108,labels=c("W30","W60","W90"))
pl<-gl(3,12,108,labels=c("P0","P1","P2"))
gp<-gl(3,36,108,labels=c("A","B","C"))
dat<-cbind(A=runif(108),B=runif(108,min=1,max=10),C=runif(108,min=100,max=200),D=runif(108,min=1000,max=1500))
dat.df<-data.frame(wt,pl,gp,dat)
dat.m<-melt(dat.df)
ggplot(dat.m,aes(x=wt,y=value,group=pl,facet=gp,fill=pl))+
        stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar",size=2,position="dodge")+
        stat_summary(fun.ymin=function(x)(mean(x)-sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))),geom="errorbar",
                    fun.ymax=function(x)(mean(x)+sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))),position="dodge")+
                    facet_grid(variable~facet,scale="free_y")+ opts(legend.position="top")+ 
                    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

[image: My output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

1. To get a horizontal legend, use `opts(legend.direction="horizontal")`
2. To change the fill of the bars, you have to specify `scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "grey20", "grey70"))`.  In your example, you have correctly mapped fill to pl.  The only missing step is to map the manual scale to fill, rather than colour.  Colour generally refers to the outline of the bar, and fill refers to the inside of the bar.
3. To rotate the angle of axis text, use `opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=45))`.  The default orientation is horizontal, so I use 45 degrees for illustration.
4. I don't know what you mean by "maybe a y-axis".  Perhaps you don't want to display the y-axis, in which case you can suppress it by `opts(axis.title.y = theme_blank())`

Note that your example was not reproducible, so I had to invent some data.  You can make it easier for us to respond if you ensure your example is reproducible:

- There is no data for `year`
- There is a reference to `trt` in your data.frame
- You set up data for `grp` but then refer to it as `gp`

My code:

```
dat.df <- data.frame(
    gp = gl(3, 36, 108, labels=c("A", "B", "C")),
    yr = sample(2000:2010, 108, replace=TRUE),
    A=runif(108),
    B=runif(108, min=1, max=10),
    C=runif(108, min=100, max=200),
    D=runif(108, min=1000, max=1500)
)
dat.m <- melt(dat.df)

ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=wt, y=value, group=pl, facet=gp, fill=pl))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", size=2, position="dodge")+
    stat_summary(fun.ymin=function(x)(mean(x)-sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), geom="errorbar", 
        fun.ymax=function(x)(mean(x)+sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), position="dodge")+#, position="dodge"
    facet_grid(variable~facet, scale="free_y")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "grey20", "grey70")) +
    opts(
        legend.position="top", 
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=45),
        axis.title.y = theme_blank()
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Andrie, and I apologize for the carelessness! I already edited the code to make it reproducible. Your answer is exactly what I want!

Comment: I'm new to R, but I think there have been changes to ggplot, to the effect that, for instance, this is the new syntax: theme( axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45) )